# What are the packages/libraries I should install before compiling Python from source?

Tags: python, development, compiling

Once in a while I need to install a new Ubuntu (I used it both for desktop and servers) and I always forget a couple of libraries I should have installed before compiling, meaning I have to recompile, and it's getting annoying.

So now I want to make a complete list of all library packages to install before compiling Python (and preferably how optional they are).

This is the list I compiled with below help and by digging in `setup.py`. It is complete for Ubuntu 10.04 and 11.04 at least:

```
build-essential (obviously)
libz-dev        (also pretty common and essential)
libreadline-dev (or the Python prompt is crap)
libncursesw5-dev
libssl-dev
libgdbm-dev
libsqlite3-dev
libbz2-dev
```

For Python 3.2 and later:

```
liblzma-dev
```

More optional:

```
tk-dev
libdb-dev
```

Ubuntu has no packages for v1.8.5 of the Berkeley database, nor (for obvious reasons) the Sun audio hardware, so the `bsddb185` and `sunaudiodev` modules will still not be built on Ubuntu, but all other modules are built with the above packages installed.

**UPDATE**

There are in Ubuntu 14.04 even more patches needed for Python 2.6, and 2.7 etc. I would recommend to instead checkout [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). It contains a script `python-build` (located in `plugins/python-build/bin`). With it you can install arbitrary Python versions like this:

```
$ ./python-build 2.7.8 /opt/python27
```

Where 2.7.8 is the version and /opt/python27 is the path it will be installed. Pyenv will download the Python version, apply the necessary patches and `configure; make; make install` for you.

**END UPDATE**

Python 2.5 and Python 2.6 also needs to have LDFLAGS set on Ubuntu 11.04 and later, to handle the new multi-arch layout:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/$(dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)"
```

For Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.0 you also need to explicitly enable SSL after running the `./configure` script and before running `make`. In `Modules/Setup` there are lines like this:

```
#SSL=/usr/local/ssl
#_ssl _ssl.c \
#       -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
#       -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Uncomment these lines and change the SSL variable to `/usr`:

```
SSL=/usr
_ssl _ssl.c \
       -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
       -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Python 2.6 and 3.0 also needs Modules/_ssl.c modified to be used with OpenSSL 1.0, which is used in Ubuntu 11.10. At around line 300 you'll find this:

```
    else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL3)
        self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_method()); /* Set up context */
    else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL2)
        self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv2_method()); /* Set up context */
    else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL23)
        self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method()); /* Set up context */
```

Change that into:

```
    else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL3)
        self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_method()); /* Set up context */
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SSL2
    else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL2)
        self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv2_method()); /* Set up context */
#endif
    else if (proto_version == PY_SSL_VERSION_SSL23)
        self->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method()); /* Set up context */
```

This disables SSL_v2 support, which apparently is gone in OpenSSL1.0.

Python 2.4 (yes, I still have some old projects that need 2.4) needs this patch to setup.py:

```
--- setup.py    2006-10-08 19:41:25.000000000 +0200
+++ setup.py        2012-05-08 14:02:14.325174357 +0200
@@ -269,6 +269,7 @@
         lib_dirs = self.compiler.library_dirs + [
             '/lib64', '/usr/lib64',
             '/lib', '/usr/lib',
+           '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'
             ]
         inc_dirs = self.compiler.include_dirs + ['/usr/include']
         exts = []
@@ -496,7 +497,8 @@
                 ssl_incs += krb5_h
         ssl_libs = find_library_file(self.compiler, 'ssl',lib_dirs,
                                      ['/usr/local/ssl/lib',
-                                      '/usr/contrib/ssl/lib/'
+                                      '/usr/contrib/ssl/lib/',
+                                     'x86_64-linux-gnu'
                                      ] )

         if (ssl_incs is not None and
```

And it needs to be compiled with:

```
env CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"  ./configure --prefix=/opt/python2.4
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are a few more. Normally, configure should remind you if anything is missing, and a few of them *are* optional. Here's my list:

```
build-essential
libncursesw5-dev
libreadline-gplv2-dev
libssl-dev
libgdbm-dev
libc6-dev
libsqlite3-dev
libbz2-dev
libffi-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, updated. Configure does remind you, but it just swooshes by, and sometimes it's not obvious what package to install.

Comment: Accepted as the only one actually answering. :) I'll try to remember to add to this question the next time I need to install an Ubuntu.  :)

Comment: For Ubuntu 12.04, you'll want to change `libreadline5-dev` to `libreadline-dev`

Comment: Thanks for all of this. The text of your answer says 'no need to install tk dev libraries', but the list includes 'tk-dev'. Am I being dumb?

Comment: More recently, libbz2-dev and liblzma-dev should also be added.

Comment: 16.10 has replaced `libreadline5-dev` with `libreadline-gplv2-dev`

Comment: @jmunsch This is also the case on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: But if I try to install `libreadline-dev`, it tries to go on installing `libncurses5` and `libncursesw5`, wtf is with these spaghetti dependencies?

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to install all build dependancies for Python with the `build-dep` option in [apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get)

`sudo apt-get build-dep python`

```
    build-dep
       build-dep causes apt-get to install/remove packages in an attempt
       to satisfy the build dependencies for a source package.
```

Comment: That's interesting. But it installs loads of things that are clearly not strictly needed (libsgmls-perl!?), while it doesn't install neither libz-dev nor libreadline-dev (see above).

Comment: This is very useful though when you `apt-get source python`.

Comment: For me, this also omits openssl, which means that after I build python, I can't install setuptools because its installer downloads over https.

Comment: this is what the official docs seem to recommend too: https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html

Comment: For greater precision you can use the command `sudo apt-get build-dep python3.x` (replace 3 and x with your preferred version as needed - though sometimes as in my case 3.6 wasn't yet available so I used 3.5 instead)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use Google App Engine SDK:

- opensll
- libssl-dev build-essential

libsqlite3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev

PIL   1.1.7

:)

Comment: You don't need PIL to compile Python. :)

Answer (score 1):

To run certain types of tests you will need `python-profiler`